# Javascript toggle with if statement

Tags: javascript

I was playing around vanilla javascript and wanted to make toggle with an `if` statement. `p` writes fine with my `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;`, but when I click again it doesn't disappear.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Visit W3Schools";
  var patt = /w3schools/i;
  var result = str.match(patt);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
  if(document.getElementById("demo") == result){
  document.getElementById("demo") = "0";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to do a case-insensitive search for "w3schools" in a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot compare `document.getElementById("demo")` directly with `result`. `document.getElementById("demo")` returns an `HTMLElement`, while `result` is an array.

Also, you're checking the contents of the element after you've already set it. In that case, the `if` statement will always evaluate to `true` and the `if` block will always execute, meaning that the text will never appear (it will be set and instantaneously removed).

Also, to remove the text, you'll need to set `.innerHTML` to an empty string (`""`), not the element to `"0"`.

The most minimal way to get your code working:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Visit W3Schools";
  var patt = /w3schools/i;
  var result = str.match(patt);

  if (document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML == result) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to do a case-insensitive search for "w3schools" in a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

---

Now, there are a couple of other improvements that could be made to your code.

`document.getElementById()` is a bit slow, so you want to just get the element once, assign it to a variable, and then use that variable instead.

Also, it's generally considered a bad practice to use `==`, `===` is preferred whenever possible. However, if you change `==` to `===` in your code, it won't work correctly. The reason is that `str.match(patt)` actually returns an array with one item. When you assign it to `.innerHTML` the browser converts it to a string, which works fine. However, when you compare `.innerHTML` with `result`, the one is a string, the other is an array, so they don't match with `===`. The solution is to do `var result = str.match(patt)[0];`, since you're only interested in the first match (remember, arrays are zero-indexed, so the first item is `0`, not `1`).

With these edits, your code would read:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Visit W3Schools";
  var patt = /w3schools/i;
  var result = str.match(patt)[0];
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo")

  if (demo.innerHTML === result) {
    demo.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    demo.innerHTML = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to do a case-insensitive search for "w3schools" in a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("demo") == result` isn't a useful comparison. The left-hand side is a DOM element, but the right-hand side is an array. Also, it doesn't make sense to assign `"0"` to a DOM element. To fix it, add `.innerHTML` to both of those, just like you have it on the preceding line. Also, match on the innerHTML, instead of on a constant `str`.

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementById("demo")` returns null or `HTMLElement` so your condition will be always false. And more than that, your `result` return will return array or null. You cannot compare your `getElementById` with `result` Here the right way you can do your condition

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Visit W3Schools";
  var patt = /w3schools/i;
  var result = str.match(patt);
  if(result){ // the right way to write your condition
    document.getElementById("demo") = "0";
  }
}
```

Update:

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Visit W3Schools";
  var patt = /w3schools/i;
  var result = str.match(patt);
  if(result){
     document.getElementById("demo") = "0";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result[0]; // result index 0 here because match return array
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not useful, I want when somebody clicks to button paragraph become firstly result and then IF paragraph is result and I click again to button paragraph to become "0".

Answer (score 0):

Their are few things that you are missing or confused.

- `str.match` return a array | so using writing `result[0]` is actually the string that matched first
- `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result[0];` should change the `p#demo` `innerHTML` to `W3Schools` and just after that you are comparing that `p` `innerHTML` with the same string that will always be true. | so it will always be "0" in `p` `innerHTML`.
- For toggling the `innerHTML` you have to add both case in `if-else` so that when

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Visit W3Schools";
  var patt = /w3schools/i;
  var result = str.match(patt);
  // if W3Schools is in innerHTML
  if (document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML == result[0]) {
    // change "0" to "" for making the innerHTML blank
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "0";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result[0];
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to do a case-insensitive search for "w3schools" in a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```